# Facing issue while upgrading Angular 9 app to Angular 12

Tags: angular12

When we are trying to update our Angular 9 application(Single SPA micro frontend) to Angular 12 we are facing bellow issue.

Error on console when trying to run this app:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
```

- configuration.output has an unknown property 'chunkLoadingGlobal'. These properties are valid:
  object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkCallbackName?, chunkFilename?, chunkLoadTimeout?, crossOriginLoading?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolNamespace?, filename?, futureEmitAssets?, globalObject?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, jsonpScriptType?, library?, libraryExport?, libraryTarget?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine?, webassemblyModuleFilename? }
  -> Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.
  See "C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-UWsPRm\angular-errors.log" for further details..

Package.json:

```
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "npm run serve",
      "devstart": "ng serve --aot=false",
      "build": "npm run build",
      "test": "ng test"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
     "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1202.13",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.14",
    "@elastic/apm-rum": "^4.5.1",
    "@elastic/apm-rum-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.6.3",
    "@grapecity/spread-excelio": "^12.0.10",
    "@grapecity/spread-sheets": "^12.0.10",
    "@grapecity/spread-sheets-angular": "^12.0.10",
    "@grapecity/spread-sheets-charts": "^12.0.10",
    "@highcharts/map-collection": "^1.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.17.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^17.4.43",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/sockjs-client": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/stompjs": "^2.3.4",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.2.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "e": "0.0.4",
    "fund": "^1.0.0",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "highcharts-exporting": "^0.1.7",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "keycloak-angular": "^6.0.0",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng": "0.0.0",
    "ng-jhipster": "^0.11.5",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-dual-listbox": "^0.2.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "7.0.1",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^8.1.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^5.0.0",
    "percentile": "^1.2.2",
    "primeflex": "^1.1.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "scss-dependency": "^1.2.0",
    "single-spa": "^5.9.3",
    "single-spa-angular": "^5.0.1",
    "slavede-ng-dual-list-box": "^1.1.5",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "terser": "^3.16.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-5-chain": "^8.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
     "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.14",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.3.20",
    "@types/chai": "4.1.7",
    "@types/chai-string": "1.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/mocha": "5.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "9.4.6",
    "browser-sync": "2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.2.2",
    "cache-loader": "2.0.1",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "chai-string": "1.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "0.5.2",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "5.8.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "husky": "1.3.1",
    "jest": "^27.4.3",
    "jest-junit": "12.3.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^11.0.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "mocha": "5.2.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "1.0.7",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "prettier": "1.16.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "thread-loader": "2.1.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "8.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.17.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.7.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't jump from Angular 9 to Angular 12. You need to go step-by-step. Reset your repo back to Angular 9 then update to Angular 10 *first*, then test and ensure everything works, then update to Angular 11, and repeat for every major version number change,  and follow the migration guides: https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-10.0

Comment: yes i follow this step by step only  -https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=9.1-12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly update the custom-webpack with ^12.1.3

```
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.3",
```